# scp_download to download multiple files based on a pattern?

Tags: r, ssh, scp

I need to download many files from a server (specifically tectia) ideally using the `ssh` package.  These files all follow the a predictable pattern across multiple sub folders.  The filepath is formatted like this

```
/directory/subfolder/A001/abcde001.csv
```

Where A001 counts up alongside the last 3 digits of the filename (/A002/abcde002.csv and so on)

In the vignette for `scp_download` it states that the `files` parameter may contain wildcards so I have tried to do something like

`scp_download(session, "/directory/subfolder/A.*/abcde.*[.]csv", to=tempdir())`

and

`scp_download(session, "directory/subfolder/A\\d{3}/abcde\\d{3}[.]csv", to=tempdir())`

but no matter which combination of patterns or wildcards I can think of (which isn't many) I only get something like

`Warning: SSH warning: scp: /directory/subfolder/A\d{3}/abcde\d{3}[.]csv: No such file or directory`

What I'm hoping to do is either find a way to do pattern matching here, or to find a way to store tectia directories as a string to be read by `scp_download`.  I've made sure that my session is connected properly and it works without attempting to pattern match, which it does.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The problem is that when you use `*` in your pattern it gets escaped when you send it to the server. However, when you request a special file name like this `/directory/subfolder/A001/abcde001.csv`, it works fine.

Finally I changed my code based on the below steps:

1. I got the list of files/folders using `ls` command with `ssh_exec_wait` function and then store them on a variable.
2. Download files in the variable separately

```sh
session <- ssh_connect("username@ip",passwd="password")
files<-capture.output(ssh_exec_wait(session, command = 'ls /directory/subfolder/A001/*'))
dnc1<- scp_download(session, files[1], to = paste0(getwd(),"/data/"))
dnc2<- scp_download(session, files[2], to = paste0(getwd(),"/data/"))
dnc3<- scp_download(session, files[3], to = paste0(getwd(),"/data/"))
```

The bottom 3 commands can be done in a loop as this could be hundreds or thousands of records.